# Why the following JavaScript code is not valid?

Tags: javascript

When the following code is executed in chrome console

```
let a, b, c;
b = 2;
a = b+1 = c = 2+3;
```

It says an error 'Invalid left-hand side assignment' for the last statement.
But when we execute the below-given code it accepts it and does not show any error.

```
let a, b, c;
a = b = c = 2+3;
```

assignment '=' is an operator so according to operator precedence in javascript, it should work fine. what do you guys think, what is the problem?

Comment: What do you expect `b+1 = c` to mean?

Comment: assignment is right associative.

Comment: In the first case it is because you are doing b+1 = c, where c cannot be assigned to b+1.

Comment: `c` can be equat to `2+3`, but `b+1` cannot be equal to `c`. In other words a variable can take on a value, but a value can't take on a variable. That would be like saying `6 = 19`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first code you would need to do

```
let a,b,c;
b=2;
a=b+1;
c=5;
```

doing

> a=b=c=2+3

works because you arent altering a value to the left of the last equal

Comment: it means we cannot have any operations on the left-hand side of the assignment operator. for example a +1 = 5 is not valid.

Comment: correct, if your trying to check if a+1 = 5 you would have to do

'a+1===5'

as that would make it a Boolean

Answer (score 1):

the `=` operator calculate first the right side and require the left side to be [lvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue).

In your second example for every assignment operator the left side is always a variable, so it works fine. but in the first example:

> let a, b, c;
>
> b = 2;
>
> a = b+1 = c = 2+3;

you trying to assign 5 into `b+1`, its simply not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need some parenthesis to make it clear what you mean:

```
 a = 1 + (b = c = 2+3);
```